# How to revoke ubuntu from accessing windows files when dual booted

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed windows 8.1 along with ubuntu 14.04  and both the volumes in windows can be accessed from ubuntu file directory. how to revoke ubuntu from doing that.. Both the c and e directory in windows is shown here in ubuntu file directory.